# If-else-if: It always give me the same result

Tags: java

Class:

```
package work;

public class col2 {

    private double color;
    private double colorO;

    public col2(int c){
        color = c;
    }

    public void setColor(int c){
        color = c;
        calcN();
    }

    public void calcN(){
        colorO = (double) color%2;
    }

    public void color0(int c){
        color = c;
    }

    public String getcolor(){
        String coco = "";

        if(color == 0){
            coco = "green";
        }
        else if (color>=1 && color<=10){
            if (colorO==0){
                coco = "red";
            }
            else if (colorO>0){
                coco = "black";
            }
        }

        return coco;
    }
}
```

main:

```
Scanner y = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("number");
int gg = y.nextInt();

col2 ko = new col2(gg);
System.out.println(ko.getcolor());
```

The problem is that whatever number I choose it always give me red as an answer.

I also tried by putting the 3 conditions in one condition but that time it gave me only black. I don't know what the problem is. I started my variable in int, then switched them in double so that the % could work.

Comment: As long as you input a number between 1 and 10, the output will be "red", because... it's doing what you told it to do.

Answer (score 1):

i think you have something wrong here

```
public col2(int c){
    color = c;
}
```

change it to

```
public col2(int c){
    color = c;
    calcN();
}
```

or

```
public col2(int c){
    setColor(c);
}
```

in your main, you init `col2 ko = new col2(gg);` it just set the `color` variable and don't set `color0` variable. The output is always "red" because the `color0` always `0` (default value of double).

Answer (score 0):

Your if statement is kind of a mess:

```
 else if (color>=1 && color<=10){
        if (colorO==0){
            coco = "red";
        }
```

if you were to put color instead of color0:

```
if (color==0){
```

Will never be true since condition above is true only when color is between 1 and 10

Also this:

```
else if (color > 0)
```

will always be true cause color is 1 to 10

Not sure why you put color0 instead of color.

Comment: If it were `color`, it would always be false.

Comment: @Anton Kim, Your statement about `color0` is wrong. You are confusing the variable `color` with `color0` - they are not the same variable.

Answer (score 0):

```
Tkx guys.
I know, generally my statements are a mess, my teacher keep saying that my variables don't have proper names.
Anyway, your answers work and that is perfect, but i found the solution sooner since the teacher asked this number. I also changed my logic and i forgot to give some details of the problems. I'm sorry about that.
Once again, tkx a lot.

Here are the codes.
```

class

```
public class opop {




        private double colorA;
        private double colorO;

        public opop(int c){
            colorA = c;
        }

        public void setColor(int c){
            colorA = c;
            //calcN();
        }

    /*  public void calcN(){
            colorO = (double) color%2;
        }

        public void color0(int c){
            color = c;
        }
        */

        public String getcolor(){
            String coco = "";
            double color= colorA%2;
            if(colorA == 0){
                coco = "green";
            }
            else if (colorA>=1 && colorA<=10){
                    if (color==0){
                        coco = "black";

                    }
                    else {
                        coco = "red";
                    }
            }


            else if (colorA>=11  && colorA<=18){
                if (color ==0){
                coco = "red";}
                else{
                    coco = "black";
                }
            }

            else if (colorA>=19 && colorA<=28){
                if(color ==0){
                coco = "black";}
                else {
                    coco = "red";
                }
            }

            else if (colorA>=29 && colorA<=36){
                if (color ==0){
                coco = "red";}
                else {
                    coco = "black";
                }
            }

            else  {
                coco = "Not good";
            }

        return coco;



        }
```

MAIN

```
public static void main(String[] args){
Scanner y = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("number");
        int gg = y.nextInt();


       opop ko = new opop(gg);
       System.out.println(ko.getcolor());
}
```